# Entropy of real substances - Is it possible to decompose arbitrary $p$-$V$ cycles of real substances in small Carnot cycles of an ideal gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, ideal-gas, carnot-cycle

In physics textbooks it is proved that $\oint\frac{δQ_{rev}}{T}=0$ by decomposing an arbitrary cycle in the $p$-$V$ diagram into infinitesimal Carnot cycles. Does the arbitrary cycle have to be a cycle of an ideal gas or can it also be a cycle of a real substance? Can you please also explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Carnot cycle is defined as cyclic reversible process working between two thermal reservoirs, using isothem-adiabat-isotherm-adiabat sequence of processes that returns to the original state. It is not limited to ideal gas. Any real working medium (substance) with any equation of state can undergo Carnot cycle. So the derivation is meant for any working medium. The only important assumptions are that the whole process is reversible, and that the First Law of thermodynamics is valid. For more complicated systems (more than 2 independent state variables), assuming the Second Law is needed to make sure this loop integral is zero.

Answer (score 2):

The relation is true for cycles of all materials. (Since the result is general, there's not really a reason "why" except that no particular material-specific equation of state was required to obtain this result.)

If an ideal gas was used in an example to motivate the derivation, it could be because (1) gas has no shear stiffness and no surface tension and therefore shifts and expands easily, making it a natural choice for thought experiments involving mechanical cycling with pistons, for example and (2) the ideal gas stores energy in the form of motion only, allowing *other* aspects of the cycling to be analyzed using its two equations of state $dU=C_VdT$ and $PV=nRT$. But these equations are not required to obtain the result you're asking about.